# Symfony too many redirect on apache server

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Despite I've searched on the web I didn't found the answer yet.

I made a simple Symfony  project working fine on dev ENV with Symfony server.

I decided to put it on apache server to preview it before some live test but I've been facing some issues.

I made a blog part that display nicely without post in it but if I add one (or more) post I have an error on too many redirects.
The dev tool says I have a lot of request like this:
 - blog
 - blog/
 - blog
 - blog/
 - ...
And crashes.

I used the symfony/apache-pack that gave me the .htaccess:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    #RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    #RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I use the apache site config following:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain
    ServerAlias www.mydomain

    # Uncomment the following line to force Apache to pass the Authorization
    # header to PHP: required for "basic_auth" under PHP-FPM and FastCGI
    #
    # SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    # For Apache 2.4.9 or higher
    # Using SetHandler avoids issues with using ProxyPassMatch in combination
    # with mod_rewrite or mod_autoindex
    #<FilesMatch \.php$>
        #SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
        # for Unix sockets, Apache 2.4.10 or higher
        # SetHandler proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.sock|fcgi://dummy
    #</FilesMatch>

    # If you use Apache version below 2.4.9 you must consider update or use this instead
    # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/public/$1

    # If you run your Symfony application on a subpath of your document root, the
    # regular expression must be changed accordingly:
    # ProxyPassMatch ^/path-to-app/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/public/$1

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile 
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

(Some parts has been changed/removed like path or domain name)

My blog controller looks like this:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/blog/articles", name="blog")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $blogpost = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(BlogPost::class)
            ->findAll();

        if (!$blogpost) {
            $nopblogost = true;
        } else {
            $nopblogost = false;
        }
        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
            'page_title' => "mon Blog",
            'message' => null,
            'page_class' => "path-blogpage",
            'blog_empty' => $nopblogost,
            'blogpost' => $blogpost
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/blog/post/{id}", name="blogpost")
     */
    public function view($id)
    {
        $blogpost = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(BlogPost::class)
            ->find($id);

        if (!$blogpost) {
            $nopblogost = true;
        } else {
            $nopblogost = false;
        }
        return $this->render('blog/view/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
            'page_title' => $blogpost->getTitre(),
            'message' => null,
            'page_class' => "path-blogpage",
            'blog_empty' => $nopblogost,
            'post' => $blogpost
        ]);
    }
```

Strange fact:
When I change the route to "blog/list" by example it works fine
Back to "blog" error again.

I don't understand has some static page are routed as "main" with subpage "main/sub" handled like the blog but without database interaction.

Anyone had the problem?

Comment: symfony by default will try to remove the trailing slash via redirect (since symfony 4.1), (your?) apache apparently tries to add the trailing slash via redirect. I would *assume* the difference being, when the folder of "deeper" levels exist or doesn't ... I strongly dislike trailing slashes ...

Comment: Ok thank you!
I am going to investigate a bit more on apache config! Might not be in the .htaccess but in VHost or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the rewrite pack,

follow the manual https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi

section 'Apache with mod_php/PHP-CGI', the config example with the allowOverride none.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the fallback resource for the asset directories
    # which will allow Apache to return a 404 error when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request to Symfony
    <Directory /var/www/project/public/bundles>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    #SetEnv APP_ENV prod
    #SetEnv APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>
    #SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name"
</VirtualHost>
```